# Jquery cross site Ajax call with 302 success data undefined with datatype script otherwise return error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery 1.7.2, trying to do a cross site Ajax request which should return a html page via 4 redirects. 
Not my ideal world with all those redirects, but it's part of the specification.

Now, using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: myUrl,

     dataType: "script",
     success: function(data) {
      alert("success :"+ data);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("revoke: "+textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown+"/"+jqXHR.status);
     },
     complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
         alert("complete : "+jqXHR.statusText + ": "+jqXHR.readyState);
     }
  });
```

I can see in Firebug/Safari Developer Tools, that all the redirects work (e.g. returns a 302 status with a Location header).
Then the strange thing happens: At the last page, which returns a 200 status, my script ends and I try to view the data coming back. But the output is just "Undefined". 
I agree on that I should not expect a script datatype when trying to get a html page, but when I tried with all the other datatypes (as defined in the [jquery ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), the error handler is envoked and the status code is 0. All the while, in Safari DT, the status after the first redirect is just set as "(canceled)" (all the while the request just for the second redirect page just hangs in Firebug - but I'm just guessing that it has to do with their different implementation).

When I receive a 200 status, I can see in the debuggers that the last page has a size of some 18kb, which means that there should be some sort of data in it.

what to do?

Comment: Well, could you post some code? Check this:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: 302 is redirect, so it will have the page you redirect to,unless it's not found

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu. You can't redirect with `ajax`...

Comment: yeah...ehh, had some issues with my browser - you know, back and forth, and didn't think that it had posted the question. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect with `AJAX`, you can only send and get data to and from the server.

For a redirection you have to use a "regular" HTTP request.

It can also be done with javascript `window.location = myUrl`

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but looking at the responses, it looks like it accepts the redirects and return the vaild data.

Comment: @MortenSkov. This is true, but the browser "ignores" the response because it's not a valid one.

Comment: Ok. Well, that's a bit of a problem for me, as I need to return to the original page to do some work with the data.

Comment: @MortenSkov. Then don't redirect from the server, just return the HTML. "Closed as by design"...

Comment: Yeah...the problem is, as I stated in the original question, that it's not really up to me. It's the design of the server.

Comment: @MortenSkov. I can't help you with that... You should accept an answer or write one yourself if you have a better one. (Of course you can wait for second opinion... `:)`)

Comment: yes...I was waiting for a second opinion. But, as nobody came up with one, I'm just gonna accept yours.
Thanks for your help.